# Date handling strategies in Python/Pandas/Numpy

Tags: date, pandas

Has anyone seen a good blog about date handling in python or particularly Pandas.  I feel like I am constantly hitting a brick wall dealing with dates in pandas, and feel I am missing a standard approach.

Basically I am interested in storing dates, but pandas is storing timestamps to nanosecond accuracy. then pandas has a Period class that allows you to put a time interval (eg day), but this isn't vectorised (for irregular dates)  and both classes  don't play well with numpy datetime64 ...

Comment: Your 1st paragraph is not in the scope of SO. I think you should specify your actual problem clearly and provide some example of what you have, what you'd like to do with those data and what you did try.

Comment: There is a blog called "pandas documentation" you should check out, it's really good!  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html